# Como seleccionar una sola fila de un txt en python

Tags: python

EL archivo txt esta conformado de la siguiente manera:

> ```
>                                       *********Reporte General*********
> Número de errores Concordancia:                   31 
> Número de errores Dequeismo:                  1 
> Número de errores Preposiciones:              3 
> Número de errores Preposiciones con Verbo:        2 
> Número de errores Cocofonia:      5 
> Número de errores Impersonal:     26 
> Número de errores Frecuentes:     3 
> Número de errores Expresiones:        3 
> Número de errores Jergas Populares:       1 
> Número de errores Anaforas:       14 
> Número de errores Infinitivo:     2 
> Número de errores Tónica:     1 
> Número de errores Rimas:      21 
> Número de errores Riqueza Lexica:     423 
>                                       *********Reporte General*********
> Número de errores Concordancia:                   2 
> Número de errores Dequeismo:                  0 
> Número de errores Preposiciones:              0 
> Número de errores Preposiciones con Verbo:        0 
> Número de errores Cocofonia:      2 
> Número de errores Impersonal:     0 
> Número de errores Frecuentes:     0 
> Número de errores Expresiones:        0 
> Número de errores Jergas Populares:       0 
> Número de errores Anaforas:       0 
> Número de errores Infinitivo:     0 
> Número de errores Tónica:     0 
> Número de errores Rimas:      3 
> Número de errores Riqueza Lexica:     9
> ```

Comment: Hola Jicastr, ¿En base a que quieres seleccionar la fila?¿Por índice?¿Según el contenido de la fila en si (por ejemplo todas aquellas con `Número de errores Rimas:`)?, etc. Otros datos pueden ser relevantes, por ejemplo, ¿vas a realizar múltiples búsquedas o solo una? ¿Es tu archivo muy extenso o no? ¿Te interesa anteponer la eficiencia en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución a la memoria o a la inversa? Es importante porque puede ser o no recomendable cargar en memoria el fichero completo o no dependiendo de estas condiciones. Por otro lado ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: quiero seleccionar en base al que tenga el numero mayor 'Número de errores Riqueza Lexica:     423 '  serán múltiples búsquedas, el archivo es  pequeño solo son 26 filas. Gracias @FJSevilla

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones este último comentario como parte de la pregunta? Sin eso realmente no hay pregunta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para seleccionar una fila de acuerdo con algún criterio puede hacerse lo siguiente:

```
import re

# Dentro de "open(archivo" deberá introducirse, entre comillas, el nombre del
# archivo de texto. Por ejemplo, si el archivo se llama 'archivo.txt':
lineas = open('archivo.txt').read().split('\n')

# El primer parámetro dentro de "re.search(primer_parametro,x)" debe de ser
# el criterio bajo el cual se quiere seleccionar alguna fila, por ejemplo,
# para encontrar la fila que contenga el número '423':

resultado = filter(lambda x: x if re.search('423',x) else None,lineas)
```

De esta manera podrá seleccionarse la fila que cumple con los criterios predeterminados:

```
print(resultado)
['Número de errores Riqueza Lexica:     423 ']
```

Si se usa python 3.x la última línea deberá de ser ligeramente diferente:

```
resultado = list(filter(lambda x: x if re.search('423',x) else None,lineas))
```

Comment: Gracias @Daniel es justo lo que estaba buscando.